# Can google compute engine instances access a common file system?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I would like to have a group of google compute engine instances have access to a common file system. Is this possible, and if so how?

It can be assumed that the instances are all running the same linux based OS (Ubuntu in my particular case).

By common file system I mean a file system than can be mounted in such a way that it can be accessed by all the normal OS commands, e.g. `cp`, `mv`, `rm` etc.

Comment: I don't get why this question's being downvoted either. People seem to hate google-compute-engine questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example by using [Google Cloud Storage Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse).

Answer (score 1):

We often setup an instance as an NFS server and have multiple VMs connect to the NFS exports via the internal network (no bandwidth costs). This keeps things portable and does not tie you down to Google Storage or something like Gluster that might not be easy to admin or migrate during emergencies.

The disk that is exported via NFS can be snapshotted easily and if it is a XFS formatted file system, it can be grown easily.

Answer (score 0):

Another, commonly used alternative, could be [Gluster](https://www.gluster.org/). GlusterFS is a scalable network filesystem. Using common off-the-shelf hardware, you can create large, distributed storage solutions for media streaming, data analysis, and other data- and bandwidth-intensive tasks. GlusterFS is free and open source software.